# extracting sentences from file that contain words, case insensitive

Tags: python

I'm working on a code that gets sentences from a textfile that contain certain words. The words are 'I', 'we', 'you'. Now I have the following code:

```
import re
f = open('file.txt', 'r')
text = ''.join(f.readlines())
sentences = re.split(r' *[\.\?!][\'"\)\]]* *', text)


def finding(q):
    for item in sentences:
        if item.find(q.lower) != -1:
            print item

finding('I')
finding('you')
finding('we')
```

So the last part is a bit sloppy. But it gets the sentences. What i would also like is to get You, and We, so words with capitals. 
I'm pretty new at this, so any help would be appreciated, also with the original code.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: minor nitpick, but `q.lower` should be `q.lower()`...

Comment: note that your code doesn't find "words", only substrings. For example, it finds "we" and "i" in "weird".

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `item.find` you can using regex for case insensitive search:

```
if re.search(r"(?i)%s" % re.escape(q), item):
```

or:

```
if item.lower().find(q.lower()) != -1:
```

Comment: Don't forget to `re.escape` if you're going to build a regular expression dynamically.

Comment: @ Aamir, Thanks for the quick response! I used your solution and it's working great. I hardly have any experience with regex, so this really helpfull.

Answer (score 1):

use regular expression in finding function

```
re.search(q, item, re.IGNORECASE)
```